# Convert to PDF's Last Page using GraphicsMagick with Python

Tags: python, pdf, graphicsmagick

To convert a range of say the 1st to 5th page of a multipage pdf into single images is fairly straight forward using:
convert file.pdf[0-4] file.jpg

But how do i convert say the 5th to the last page when i dont know the number of pages in the pdf?

In ImageMagick "-1"represents the last page, so:
convert file.pdf[4--1] file.jpg works, great stuff,
but it doesnt work in GraphicsMagick.

Is there a way of doing this easily or do i need to find the number of pages? 
PS: need to use graphicsmagick instead of imagemagick.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: My humble offering to count the number of pages... `pdfinfo SomeDocument.pdf | awk '/^Pages:/ {print $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

Future readers of this, if you're experiencing the same dilemma in GraphicsMagick. Here's the easy solution:

Simply write a big number to represent the "last page".
That is: something like:

convert file.pdf[4-99999] +adjoin file%02d.jpg

will work to convert from the 5th pdf page to the last pdf page, into jpgs.

Note: "+adjoin" & "%02d" have to do with getting all the images rather than just the last. You'll see what i mean if you try it.